# MS Access table subform refresh

Tags: ms-access

I'd like to refresh the table located under the History tab whenever I enter new data under Payments. I tried adding an onclick macro when History tab is clicked but the new macro editor in Access 2010 confuses me.

As can be seen in the picture below, I've already added a fourth entry in Payments subform and the new entry does not show up in the table under History Tab.

I think Refresh or requery is the way to go but I don't know how to set it up to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to run the requery would be the After Update event for the payments subform.

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Parent.HistorySubformConrolName.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

Make sure you use the name of the subform control, not the name of the form contained. See http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Creating events: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-events-and-event-procedures-HP005186744.aspx

EDIT in this particular case:

```
Me.Parent.Payment_Info.Form.Requery
```

Comment: The name of my forms is Main_Form (main form) and Payment_Form (subform) should I code it like this: 'Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Main_Form.HistoryPayment_Form.Form.Requery
End Sub' or 'Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Parent.HistorySubformConrolName.Payment_Form.Requery
End Sub'

Comment: You should run the code in the payment subform, so you do not want to refer to `Me.Main_Form`, you want to refer to the `Parent` property of the subform, so `Me.Parent.HistoryPayment_Form.Form.Requery` but you must make sure that `HistoryPayment_Form` is the name of the subform control, not the name of the form contained by the control.

Comment: The name of the History Tab control is "History" and the subform control box under the History Tab is "Payment_Info" so should it be Me.Parent.HistoryPayment_Info.Form.Requery or Me.Parent.Payment_Form.Form.Requery or Me.Parent.HistoryPayment_Form.Form.Requery? And I'm going to put this in Payment_Form's After Update event, not in Main_Form's After Update event right?

Comment: Yes, the payment form after update event. Tabs do not count. You just need the name of the History subform control. I am completely confused by the mixture of payment forms on history tabs.

Comment: Here's the setting in visual form that didn't work: http://postimage.org/image/8du9zgto7/ I'm also confused as to what is the subform control name. XD

Answer (score -1):

Me.qryListExpertsHistory_subform.Requery

' qryListExpertsHistory_subform (is the embedded form)

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem